# csr function in splancs package generates points outside polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

When generating a point pattern for the continental US using the `csr` function in the `splancs` package, I have found that some points are generated in small sections of Lake Michigan and Lake Erie. An example is below.

```
# Load packages
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(splancs)

# Obtain coordinates of US polygon
usa <- map_data("usa")
country <- usa[c(1,2)]
colnames(country) <- c("x", "y")
country <- as.points(country)

# Generate points under complete spatial randomness
random <- csr(country, 30000)
random <- data.frame(random)

# Obtain coordinates of state outlines
state <- map_data("state")

# Plot the points on a map of the US
p <- ggplot(state, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
geom_path(color = "black", aes(group = group)) +
geom_point(data = random, size = 0.7, aes(x = xc, y = yc), color = "gray") +
theme_bw()
p
```

The above code generates a map which clearly has some points on Lake Michigan and Lake Erie. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Splancs' `csr` function only works properly for simple single-ring polygons. In order to see exactly what you are feeding it, use `polymap`:

```
polymap(country)
```

[image]

Oops. Your country polygon has some oddities in it. Get a better polygon.